# How do I properly print out an array with numbers without showing symbols everytime I run it

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 50
void encryptmessage1(char[][6]);
void encryptmessage2(char[][6]);
char temparr[MAXSIZE] = {0};
int length ;
int
main()
{

    char array[5][6] = {
        {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'},
        {'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'},
        {'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O'},
        {'P', 'Q', 'Z', 'R', 'S', 'T'},
        {'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y'}
    };
   int choice;

    printf(
        "********************************\n"
        "**ENCRYPTION/DECRYPTION SYSTEM**\n"
        "********************************\n"
        "1. Code the message\n"
        "2. Decode the message\n"
        "3. EXIT\n"
        "Make your choice: "
    );
   scanf("%d",&choice);
    while (  choice != EOF )   {
        switch (choice) {
    case 1:
        encryptmessage1(array);
        encryptmessage2(array);
        break;

    case 2:
        // decrypt message
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
}
void
encryptmessage1(char array[][6])
{
    int i, j, loop, k = 0, row, col, len = 0;
    char str[MAXSIZE] = {0};
                     // temporary array

    printf("Please enter your message : ");
    fgets(str,MAXSIZE,stdin);

    // reads string
    while ((str[k] = getchar()) != '\n') {
        k++;
    }
    i = 0;

    // loop to temporary store values from another array
    for (loop = 0; loop < MAXSIZE; loop++) {
        temparr[loop] = str[loop];
    }

    // Calculating length of the array
    len = sizeof(str) / sizeof(str[0]);
    // Checks for space character in array if its there then ignores it
    // and swap str[i] to str[i+1];
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            for (j = i; j < len; j++) {
                str[j] = str[j + 1];
            }
            len--;
        }
    }

    i = 0;
    // from lowercase to uppercase
    while (str[i] != '\n') {
        if (islower(str[i])) {
            str[i] = toupper(str[i]);
        }
        i++;

    }
    puts(str);

    i = 0;
    k = 0;
    while (str[k] != '\n') {
        for (row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
                if (str[k] == array[row][col]) {

                    temparr[i] = '0' + row;
                    temparr[i + 1] = '0' + col;
                    i += 2;
                }

            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    length=i;
   puts(temparr);
   }


void
encryptmessage2(char array[][6])
{
int i, j,k =0,row,col;
char key[MAXSIZE] = {0};// keyword
char temp;
char numarray[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];

    printf("Please enter your key : ");


// reads string
    while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n') {
        key[k]=temp;
        k++;
    }
    i = 0;


// array from lowercase to uppercase
    while (key[i] != '\n') {
        if (islower(key[i])) {
            key[i] = toupper(key[i]);
        }
        i++;

    }

//Printing the array with spaces

    for(i = 0; key[i]; i++) {
        putchar(key[i]);
        putchar(' ');
    }
    putchar('\n');

//calculating the size of the array
int size = i;

i=0;
k=0;
while(i<length)
{
        for(j=0;j<size;j++){
        numarray[k][j]=temparr[i];
           i++;
            if(i<length)
                break;
        }

        k++;

    }
int columns = k;
for(i=0;i<size;i++) {
for(j=0;j<columns;j++) {

    printf("%c",numarray[i][j]);
}
printf("\n");
}

}
```

Expected output:
[image]

Actual output:
[image]
The aim for this program is to encrypt a certain message with the help of a keyword after its encrypted with the matching numbers for each letter the numbers should be printed out as an array
I have been trying to print out the actual values as an array inside my encryptionmessage2 function but when printing out it shows me emojis.

Comment: @XIz This code snippet     printf("Please enter your message : ");
    fgets(str,MAXSIZE,stdin);

    // reads string
    while ((str[k] = getchar()) != '\n') {
        k++;
    } does not make sense.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the problem is that the numbers printed under the text message should be in an array below the keyword

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd8mR.png @VladfromMoscow

Comment: character arrays are not null terminated.  you're trying to print them using string (i.e null terminated character arrays) functions (i.e. `puts`)\

Comment: @XIz – Why do numbers in your _Expected output_ differ from the digits line in your _Actual output_?